# Coefficients of a polynomial in powers of 10

Tags: functions, polynomials

Can I express a polynomial function in Mathematica in power (`ScientificForm`) ?
I was trying:

```
f[x_] = 10000 x^5 + 1278 x^4 + 113 x^3 + 89 x^2 + x + 12;
Print[ScientificForm[f[x]]];
```

But it gives me `12+x+89 x^2+113 x^3+1278 x^4+10000 x^5` whereas I was looking 
something like `10^5 x^5 + 1.2X10^3 x^4 + 1.1X10^2 x^3 + 8.9X10^1+x+12`.

Is it possible? Note that I may not want to keep all the numbers after the decimal point. Here in the example, I preferred one place after the decimal point.

Comment: Try making the numbers floating point rather than integers, i.e., 10000.0 and 1278.0 instead of 10000 and 1278

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [N](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html)

```
f[x_] = 10000 x^5 + 1278 x^4 + 113 x^3 + 89 x^2 + x + 12;
ScientificForm[N[f[x]]]
```

[image]

```
equ = N[10000 x^5 + 1278 x^4 + 113 x^3 + 89 x^2 + x + 12]
```

[image]

```
ScientificForm[%, 3]
```

[image]

[How to | Change the Format of Numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ChangeTheFormatOfNumbers.html), is for more reading.